# Where are huraths described?

Tags: monsters, published-adventures, numenera

I am GMing the Numenera adventure, "Shadewalker".  The adventure notes mention that the townspeople are afraid of huraths, but the description is limited to:

> ...snakelike animals about the size of a tall human with multiple vestigial limbs; they lurk in tall grass and can climb trees, but normally attack only solitary creatures.

And in the call-out:

> ***Hurath:*** *level 2*

Are huraths described in more detail in any of the other books?

Comment: What more do you need?  You've got body shape, habits, and attack pattern.

Comment: I probably don't "need" more, but I enjoy the more detailed descriptions in the Core book.  Is that kind of detail available anywhere? I'm more than happy to write it myself, but I'm enjoying exploring the world with my players.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I posted this same question on the Monte Cook Games Asset Team Chat page on Facebook. That page is used by MCG to communicate with volunteers who demo their products in stores.

Sean K. Reynelds confirmed that huraths are not included in any other book. He just made them up as an interesting detail for the adventure.

[image]

> **I have a group playing through Shadewalker.  Some of the NPC notes mention a fear of "huraths".  Are huraths described in either the Bestiaries or any other book?**
>
> No, they're a creature I made up.  They're not encountered in the adventure, except as a dead animal the injured hunter has.